# Deepcheck error - unintialised data 'db'

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef enum ss{
 a,
 b
}s;
int get(s *dbb)
{
 *dbb = 1;
 return 1;
}
int printss(s dbs)
{
  printf("db no is:%d",dbs);
  return 2;
}
int main()
{
 s db;
 get(&db);
 printss(db);
 return 0;
}
```

I am getting the deepcheck warning as "unintialised variable" db in the function printss. 
But i'm intialising the variable in the function get and using the variable in the function printss.Please help me find the problem

Comment: Is this using WIPRO deepcheck?

Comment: i am not getting any warning with -Wall -Wextra

Comment: You do not actually _initialize_ the variable in `main`. The value will be set in `get`, but it's not initialized (i.e. assigned to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `db` to any value before using `get` to get it:

```
int main()
{
 s db = a; // dummy value for initialization only
 get(&db);  // really setting the value of db.
 printss(db);
 return 0;
}
```